# Debug mode throws #include errors that release mode doesn't

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include, std

So I've just switched my project in Visual Studio to Debug mode because I have a more difficult issue I need to troubleshoot.  All of the sudden now when I try to compile, I get a ton of errors.  Most of them being along the lines of the following:

> error C2039: 'ostream': is not a member of 'std'

Now specific to this error, I have a file.h and file.cpp

wrappers.h includes are as follows:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shldisp.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
```

wrappers.cpp

```
#include "wrappers.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
```

Now, the release mode understands this just fine and gives no errors, but the Debug mode seems to not be pulling in wrappers.h's includes.

If I organize the files as follows:

wrappers.h

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shldisp.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
```

wrappers.cpp

```
#include "wrappers.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
```

Then suddenly the error goes away.  Why would this be happening and how should I go about fixing it?

Comment: Check that Debug and Release mode include paths are exactly match - For example select "All Configurations" and see if the paths are still visible or you see `<different options>`

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks!  That helped!  Totally didn't realize that was the issue.